# Keep a User name when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, button

How can I keep the name of the User in the Home Page even when he navigates through other pages and then comes back to the Home Page again?
It's a simple Button through which, once clicked, a prompt asks for the Users name and displays a greeting.

For example:
**Button:** Who are you?
**Prompt:** Insert your name
**Message Displayed:** Hi *[Name]*, welcome to the WebSite!

The problem is that when the User refresh the Home Page, the name disappear and he should click again the button.

Is there any way to keep the User Name in the whole session?

Thanks!

Comment: You can save it as cookie

Comment: You can use localStroage. Look at those [`localStorage` Mozilla ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [`localStorage` w3schools ref](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Try using local storage, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: what have you tried so far? This is not a `write my code platform`....you are saving the data into the browsers memory which will be released on reloading the page....thus you have to use the localStorage or even `cookies`

Comment: Use localStorage if you need to store the name until the user clear the browser localStorage, use sessionStorage if you need to save it only during the user session.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `localStorage` like this

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "Smith");
```

to get the value from the `localStorage` use this

```
localStorage.getItem("username");
```

Comment: and to get the `username` value use `localStorage.getItem("username")`

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use sessionStroge like this.

```
 // Store
sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

You can Retrieve more information about this function
[w3schools:SessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

@andrea-belluccia you can store it in a session, cookie or localstorage (you should check browser compatibility list for this). Then whenever you need to use the username you can.